Why doesn't Mongoose's findById() method increment _id_ index usage in Mongo?
I have a collection where records are typically looked up directly by their _id property.  This is done thousands of times per day by the backend application using Mongoose's findById() method.
When I look at the usage for the _id_ index on the collection automatically created by Mongo, it only reports 60 uses in the past ~2 weeks.  This is much lower than I would expect relative to how frequently records in the collection are read this way.  Furthermore, I have confirmed that the frontend workflow that triggers the findById() calls does not increment the index usage by comparing the usage across calls that I'm making personally.
Interestingly, running a query of the form { _id: UUID("<uuid>") } from the Compass GUI does increment the index usage.
I'm curious why the findById() calls don't increment the index usage.  If those calls aren't leveraging the index, what is the mechanism that they're using to look up the records?  Is it possible that I have some kind of schema misconfiguration that is resulting in collection scans to find records by their _id?
A few explanations I've considered and ruled out

There is no caching layer in the stack (aside from automatic DB caching...?) that would be intercepting these requests before they make it to the database
The documentation suggests that the primary purpose of this index is to ensure uniqueness for the _id_ property.  So it occurred to me that perhaps this index isn't used for lookups.  But this doesn't make sense because

Compass uses it for queries submitted there as I mentioned above
_id_ indices for other collections in the instance have much higher usage



Other potentially relevant information

The backend is nestjs
The database is a MongoDB Atlas M10 instance

Edit(s)

I'm getting the index usage numbers from the Compass/Atlas GUI's "indexes" tab for the collection


Are you using $indexStats ? It reports access from current primary only. Re-elections and secondary reads screw the metric.  Atlas is DaaS and you are eligible to challenge their support. Kindly share their explanations, it's an interesting question.

Oh my gosh @AlexBlex that must be it!!  Our client even uses the "prefer secondary" read preference.  Thank you!
I've updated the question to indicate where I'm viewing the stats on index usage.  I'll contact Atlas/Compass support and post a more thorough answer when I have one!
